# How can I switch authorized facebook user with Facebook Android SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I have successfully implemented authorization with facebook in my native android app.

Now I have following problem:

User logout from my app and I call facebook sdk logout method. But when user presses login button it automatically redirects back to my app without showing "Already authorized" window, so he cannot switch to another user.

Is that normal behavior or I've made something wrong? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It seems that when the user has an opened session with the official facebook app, then, it never ask for permission in our android app. Try closing the session in the official FB app.

Comment: @BlueVoodoo The user has to close the session in the official FB app in the phone, not only in "our custom app".

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to switch to another user, you can refer to the "SwitchUserSample" in [Facebook SDK for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/).

Here is some example code fyi.

```
Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
currentSession.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
newSession = new Session.Builder(LoginActivity.this).build();
newSession.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(LoginActivity.this)
                            .setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO)
                            .setCallback(statusCallback));
```

Answer (score 0):

No that's not default we can switch user. While you are doing Logout you are not clearing credentials properly so such problems arise , so you need to remove credentials perfectly.

You should got through the [HackBook code given by Facebook](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) for all features , where you have to save you Facebook object in SessionStore class and handle it accordingly :

```
 private class SessionListener implements AuthListener, LogoutListener {

    @Override
    public void onAuthSucceed() {
        setImageResource(R.drawable.logout_button);
        SessionStore.save(mFb, getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthFail(String error) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogoutBegin() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogoutFinish() {
        SessionStore.clear(getContext());
        setImageResource(R.drawable.login_button);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried Hackbook sample. It has the same problem. When I logout and login again it doesn't show "Already Authorized screen".